# MPAndroidChart - how to reduce the amount of entries to display

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart to display Linecharts in my Android Application. Some of my Linecharts have a hugh amount of data which I add to a LineDataSet. When I display
the data on the screen, it becomes quite confusing for the user because the dots are so close to each other. So I am looking for a possiblity to display e.g. only every
fith data dot on the chart.

```
        LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, mViewModel.getMeterUnit().getValue()); 
        dataSet.setColor(Color.RED);
        dataSet.setDrawValues(false); 
        dataSet.setCircleColor(Color.BLACK);
        dataSet.setCircleHoleColor(Color.BLACK);

        XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new LineBarMeasurementFragment.LineChartXAxisValueFormatter());
        xAxis.setLabelCount(0);

        for (LimitLine l1 : limitLines) {
            xAxis.addLimitLine(l1);
        }

        MinMax mx = getXMinMax(measurementList) ;

        xAxis.setAxisMaximum(mx.getxMax());
        xAxis.setAxisMinimum(mx.getxMin());

        chart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(getYAxisMin(measurementList));

        chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

        chart.getDescription().setText(mViewModel.getMeterIdentifier().getValue());


        LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSet); 
        chart.setData(lineData);
        
        // something like chart.displayOnly(5) 
        
        chart.invalidate();
```

Comment: Have you tried just showing two data sets (one full set with lines and no markers, and one down-sampled data set over top of it with markers and no lines)?

Comment: that seems to be an excellent idea, I will try this. Thanks